# How to use stringmap fold correctly in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a list of tuples of key and value pairs from a map  using Stringmap fold, but I'm getting a syntax error in response.

```
let testlist = Stringmap.fold (fun k v -> (k,v)) mymap []
```

(Assume mymap is already defined)

My terminal says

```
File "myfile.mll", line 47, characters 0-3:
Error: Syntax error
make: *** [myfile] Error 2
```

But I can't tell what my issue (and also I wish there was more information to help me).

Comment: Can you show us the rest of myfille.mll??

Comment: As @Chris suggests, it's not possible to tell what your problem is from such a small amount of information. You should supply a full example (but as small as possible) that shows the problem.  FWIW I don't see a syntax error in this one line, but it definitely has a type error. The folded function should have three parameters and yours has only two.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield But I thought I have 3 parameters? My function, mymap and []?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mll-files have special rules that doesn't allow you to use the OCaml syntax everywhere. There are special locations, like in a preambles, where you can add your OCaml definitions. Consult the [documentation](https://ocaml.org/manual/lexyacc.html) for extra details.

P.S. your definition is syntactically valid OCaml, no problem with that.